# Cannot run python file on command line with Python 3.8.0; it invokes python interpreter instead

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python file, test.py
and when I try to run it in Terminal using $ python test.py ,
it doesn't run as it's supposed to, and invokes python interpreter instead.

I have installed python 3.8.0.

The code in the python file is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python 
print("Hello World!")
```

It should print
Hello World!

Instead it invokes python interpreter:

```
$ python test.py 
Python 3.8.0 (v3.8.0:fa919fdf25, Oct 14 2019, 10:23:27) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Try: `python3 test.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the output of `which python`.
It may be an alias of `ipython -i` or something.

Comment: The start message of Python in the question clearly states the OS: `[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin`